# Connect with redis on another gear in openshift

Tags: redis, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I created 2 gears, php-5.4 and nodejs+redis.

How do I connect with Redis from my PHP gear? Where do I change the configuration?

I am using this redis cartridge:

https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your nodejs + redis application as a scaled application, that way redis will be on it's own gear, then you can use the supplied connection credentials to connect to it from your php gear.